# Whats the meaning of the phrase "Whats not to like"?

Tags: phrases

Can you please explain some of the usages as well?

Comment: As far as usage is concerned. As a  non-native English speaker, please don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a compliment - *what is there [about the thing we're discussing] that someone wouldn't like? Nothing, right?* So for example, discussing a vacation possibility:

> Sun, sand, warm breezes, rum drinks with umbrellas in them, what's not to like?

Language being what it is, people sometimes use it sarcastically to emphasize how much they dislike something:

> Traffic, noise, smells, people pushing and shoving, pickpockets, what's not to like?

Without context nobody can know which meaning is intended so please edit your question to include where you heard it and what you thought it meant (from tone of voice and reactions of others.)

Comment: Good points.  Take TWO people with widely divergent views on good vacation spots.  One person loves a vacation in the tropics in the middle of winter, and the other person favors a vacation in New England in the fall.  The fan of fall asks the winter-in-the-tropics guy, "But what's not to like about New England in the fall?"  The response:  "It's too cold for me; most of New England has lousy beaches; and I don't like the conservative and uptight people I've met in New England."  Person number two then turns the tables and asks, "What's not to like about winter in the tropics?" and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Generally used rhetorically, it literally means "What [about this topic] would someone dislike?" and generally implies that the answer is "nothing" (nothing not to like, ergo, everything to like). However, like many well-known English phrases, it can be used to imply that the answer is the opposite of the "usual" answer, namely that there's everything to dislike.